# C# Asp.net Telerik How to put to RadGrids side by side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Problem: 
I want to put two radgrids side by side and i couldnt do that by using the splitter, any ideas ?

My Code:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="Splitter1" runat="server" Width="1007px">
  <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server">
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </telerik:RadGrid>
      <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server">
          <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
          </telerik:RadGrid>
      </telerik:RadPane>
  </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

[image: How i want the radgrids to be]

Comment: Even tried this: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/splitterorientation/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: So that the `Orientation="Vertical"` doesn't work here? Probably somewhat CSS settings may be used.

Comment: Nope didnt help to put the radsplitter to vertical or just move the panes around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Designer shows that the design is wrong when its actually working with my original code. 
Thanks for helping anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

because you put RadPane2 inside in RadPan1. You must change like this:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="Splitter1" runat="server" Width="1007px">
<telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server">
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadPane>
<telerik:RadSplitBar ID="RadSplitbar1" runat="server" CollapseMode="Forward">
</telerik:RadSplitBar>
<telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server">
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
</telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```